# I don't understand why my sort isn't working

Tags: c#

My algoritm

1) i have empty completeTask List,  and compare with task i try to find the task which doesn't have the dependences (it's task_e)
when did it, I add to complete list firt task(I need just a name of task becauce I compare the name of  dependences and name of task) and place it to first position.

2) we have first task which we did - task_e it's our first dependence. 
now i must find all task which have their dependece, and do it. 
when I will do it i add it to completeTask list and make do other tasks

it's my algoritm

```
        public static void Sort(Task[] tasks)
        {
        List<String> completedTaskName = new List<String>();

        Task temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < tasks.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!tasks[j].Dependencies.Except(completedTaskName).Any())
                {
                    temp = tasks[i];
                    tasks[i] = tasks[j];
                    tasks[j] = temp;

                    completedTaskName.Add(tasks[i].Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it done not correctly result when i sort

```
new Task("a", "b", "c"),
new Task("b"),
new Task("c", "b"),
```

Comment: You create a new list called completeTask, then add all the tasks to it, then you throw it away. I don't think that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: You are not using the ``completeTask`` var, so when your method finishes, that var is mark as unused and then the garbage collector frees it.

Comment: His sort algorithm tries to find the "next" task and this is sorted in place, then added to the `completeTask` list, which is used to figure out which task is the next one. At least that's how I understood the approach here.

Comment: You created a list of strings, not a list of tasks, as requested. Write `var completeTask = new List<Task>();` and add it the task directly `completeTask.Add(tasks[i]);`. Your method must have the return type `List<Task>()` instead of `void` and at the end `return completeTask;`. Note that this creates a new list. The original list remains unchanged.

Comment: @Andrei The reason why people are not understanding your approach is that you have made no attempt at explaining how your sort is supposed to work, you're just asking "why isn't it working". If you want to avoid people getting hung up on the wrong stuff, please describe your algorithm.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes He's modifying `tasks` array in-place, the `completeTask` is used to handle dependencies on already sorted-into-place tasks, which is why it is using strings (the name of the tasks) and not the tasks themselves.

Comment: Aron - in first step i try to find `new Task("task_e")` (task without something dependences) and when i find it i add the name of complete task to array (that mean i find first dependence)  and place it in first position of array,
next step find all tasks which denpendence from  task_e and add place their  and do it with all tasks

Comment: @Andre Try bubbling *down* in the inner loop: `for (int j = tasks.Length - 1; j > i; j--)`. Also move the addition to the `completeTask` list out of the `j` loop and into the bottom of the `i` loop, you only add the task you just sorted into place.

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen - you don't know which task step by step by each other 
i try one by one find and sort all the tasks

Comment: See if this is what you want - not really tested all that much: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/bec753a3f53aa9dc460de1457943e8a3

Comment: Side note: It's the framework also has a `class Task`, not a good idea to use that name.

Comment: It works (at least with the provided example), if you exit the inner loop with `break;` after `completeTask.Add(tasks[i].Name);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you necessarily need to apply the sorting on the same array, because if you could make a copy and append to list in the order tasks would complete, it would be much easier.
Utilizing the same LINQ methods as in your example, you could simply move the tasks from one list to another in the order they are completed based on their dependencies, like the following.

```
    private static List<Task> Sort(Task[] tasks)
    {
        var completedTasks = new List<Task>();
        var uncompletedTasks = tasks.ToList();
        while (uncompletedTasks.Any())
        {
            var taskToComplete = uncompletedTasks
                .FirstOrDefault(task => !task.Dependencies.Except(completedTasks.Select(x => x.Name)).Any());

            if (taskToComplete == null)
            {
                // Cross dependency between tasks
                Console.WriteLine($"Cross dependency between the tasks: {string.Join(", ", uncompletedTasks.Select(task => task.Name))}");
                break;
            }

            completedTasks.Add(taskToComplete);
            uncompletedTasks.Remove(taskToComplete);
        }

        return completedTasks;
    }
```

Then instead of `Sort(tasks)` simply do `var sortedTasks = Sort(tasks)`

Answer (score 2):

Comments to OP have already underlined some problems in your code:

- you are trying to create a sorted List, but you discard it
- you are using Task for your class name, which is not a good idea, given that a class Task already exists in .Net framework

Anyway, you should not try to implement your sorting algorithm, .Net framework already implements (a few) good algorithims for you. Don't reinvent the wheel

You need just to specify how two objects (two Task in your case) should be compared.

You can create your own TaskComparer, implementing : `IComparer<Task>`, and use the comparer in (e.g) Linq `OrderBy` or `List<Task>.Sort`

Something like this should work:

```
public class TaskComparer: IComparer<Task>
{
    public virtual int Compare(Task t1, Task t2)
    {
        // second task is included in first task dependencies, it should be considered "bigger" than first
        if (t1.Dependencies.Contains(t2.Name))
            return 1;

        // first task is included in second task dependencies, it should be considered "bigger" than second
        if (t2.Dependencies.Contains(t1.Name))
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    // The following array is an example of specific tasks and dependencies between them.
    // For example the following constructor:
    // new Task("task_a", "task_c")
    // means that task_a may be started only after task_c is complete
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        new Task("task_a", "task_c"),
        new Task("task_b", "task_c"),
        new Task("task_c", "task_e"),
        new Task("task_d", "task_a", "task_e"),
        new Task("task_e"),
    };

    var sortedList = tasks.OrderBy(t => t, new TaskComparer()).ToList();
    foreach (Task t in sortedList)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);

    Console.WriteLine();

    // another set of data
    tasks = new Task[]
    {
        new Task("task_a", "task_b", "task_c"),
        new Task("task_b"),
        new Task("task_c", "task_b"),
    };

    sortedList = tasks.OrderBy(t => t, new TaskComparer()).ToList();
    foreach (Task t in sortedList)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
task_e
task_c
task_a
task_b
task_d

task_b
task_c
task_a
```

See it at work [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/59MTzU)